# Toasting a message after starting activity from card view

Tags: java, android, layout, toast, android-glide

I am here with a fresh question. I have a card layout in a fragment. One of the card has a button upon click which I open a new activity.

```
if("activity1".equals(button.getTag())){

                        Intent intent1 = new Intent(itemView.getContext(), MainActivity2.class);
                        itemView.getContext().startActivity(intent1);

                    }
```

My MainActivity2.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        images = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new GalleryAdapter(getApplicationContext(), images);

        RecyclerView.LayoutManager mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
        recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

MainActivity2 loads images from a server. When I click the button and open open, MainActivity2.java, I want to toast a message "Please wait while we load things for you". I tried the below:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
     Toast.makeText(this, this.getIntent().getExtras().getString("value"),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

But its not working. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the "value" extra? where it comes from?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please wait while we load things for you", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have another requirement. As explained, on clicking the new activity open, in which images are loaded. I am Toasting the message on opening the activity. Now how can I achieve the below:

When the user clicks, the new activity opens up. If there is a net connection, the message is  "Please wait while we load things for you" is loaded. If there is no net connection, instead of the above message, the message "Please enure you are connected with net" is displayed.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42376891/5281581) you have my answer for similar requirement.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

**MainActivity2.java**

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);

    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please wait while we load things for you",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

How to use `Toast`?    See [Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)